# Get certain word in URL and delete what is not necessary

Tags: php, facebook, preg-match

Example is:

https://www.facebook.com/SkyNewsArabia/photos/a.228510053865995.71265.167635259953475/712676228782706/?type=1&relevant_count=1

With or without last slash "/" and this part `"?type=1&relevant_count=1"`. I need only 712676228782706.

I tried this:

```
<?php

preg_match("/[^\/]+$/", "https://www.facebook.com/SkyNewsArabia/photos/a.228510053865995.71265.167635259953475/712676228782706/?type=1&relevant_count=1", $matches);
$last_word = $matches[0]; 

echo $last_word;
?>
```

but result was `?type=1&relevant_count=1`.
Can anyone help me with this

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you use [`parse_url`](http://php.net/parse_url)?

```
<?php

$last_word = parse_url('https://www.facebook.com/SkyNewsArabia/photos/a.228510053865995.71265.167635259953475/712676228782706/?type=1&relevant_count=1');
$last_word = explode('/', $last_word['path']);
$last_word = $last_word[4];

echo $last_word;
```

[Output](http://codepad.org/DGf9zBVo): 712676228782706